# HTML - Formatting Horizontal Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am having difficulties to format the navigation bar. I want the width to be in a fixed size and also the blocks to be properly in equal sizes. I may solve this by adjusting the padding size in CSS file but it will not have the standard size when the webpage is displayed on various sizes of computer screen. Need help on this.

```css
body {
  background-color: linen;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

ul.topnav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--Importing CSS file-->

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
<!--End of import-->

<body>

  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">VCT Operation</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mainFrame.asp">Conduct Operation</a>
        <a href="report.asp">View Reports</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does the **intended** display look like? The statements "*properly in equal sizes*" and "*the standard size*" are both rather vague. Do you want the links centralised? Do you want the highlight to occupy the full width? What about the dropdown for VCT Operation? Please update your question to specify **exactly** what you want the display to look like.

Comment: use `ul.topnav li {
    width: 33.3%;
}`

Comment: @ObsidianAge Hi, Obi. What I intended to say was regarding the navigation bar itself, I am unable to make it as a 'fixed width size' where I can have a size which fits to computer screen with different sizes.

Comment: @lalitbhakuni Thank you. But it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `display:flex` to `ul.topnav` , but make sure you use a media query, so you can give the display at the resolution you want. Reason why i added the `display:flex` is so i can align them in a column.

```
@media (max-width:760px) {
  ul.topnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

}

You can also add a `width` and another `padding` to `ul.topnav li a` , so that every `a` have the same width.

```
@media (max-width:760px) {
  ul.topnav li a {
    width: 46%;
    padding:20px 20px 20px 103px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Example: ( change the resolution to 760px )

https://jsfiddle.net/fzy7cysf/1/

Comment: Thanks a bunch, man. It works perfectly with the responsive but the 'flex-direction' doesn't seem to respond. Moreover, may I please know how to standardize each column size on the navigation bar. The sizes does not seem to be same.

Comment: the size is the same when you go below 760px, because that's how i made it to be. If you want the size to be the same at every resolution, then you can make multiple breakpoints using `media` queries

Answer (score 0):

remove padding in  `a` tag add `width:100%` and `padding 10px 0 :` li width will be '33.3%`

```
ul.topnav li { width:33.3%;}
ul.topnav li a { display:inline-block; width:100%; padding:12px 0;}
```